# " mv * dir " doesn't work in a script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to move all the files to a new dir. From the command line I can do "mv *.* newdir" but if I try with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
#
mkdir newdir
mv *.* newdir
```

I get the following message:

```
mv: rename *.* to newdir/*.*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your script reads like:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
```

You are passing the `-f` switch to bash when the script is invoked. This causes the shell to disable file name expansion, which is also known as globbing or pattern matching. Remove that `-f` from the shebang line.

Also, you should note that to select all files in bash you use just "`*`", and not "`*.*`". The later would select only files with a dot in their names. This may also cause you to try to put the directory into itself, which is an invalid operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move all files, try this:

mkdir newdir

find . -type f -exec mv "{}" newdir \;

Comment: Because "mv . newdir" attempts to move your current directory into a subdirectory and makes no sense.

Comment: May make no sense, it may be invalid, but it is not unsafe. You suggestion moves only files, leaving directories in the same place. So it has a very different meaning than what the poster is trying to do.

Comment: I concede to your point about safety!  I'm editing that out of my answer.